# Sort data from object into PHP multiassoc array

Tags: php

I have an array of objects that contains the data I need.

Here's an example object from the array:

```
$obj->category = 'foo';
$obj->date = '2015-01-14';
$obj->value = 'some value';
```

I want $obj->category to be the main key, then I want $obj->date to the key inside the category array.

I want the array to look like this:

```
Array
(
[foo] => Array
    (
        [2015-01-14] => 'some value'
        [2015-01-15] => 'some value'
    )

[bar] => Array
    (
        [2015-01-14] => 'some value'
        [2015-01-15] => 'some value'
    )

[baz] => Array
    (
        [2015-01-14] => 'some value'
        [2015-01-15] => 'some value'
    )
```

)

How do I create and populate the array in a neat way?

--- EDIT ---

I tried this:

```
$keys = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
foreach ($objects as $object) {
     foreach ($keys as $key) {
         $array[$key] = array($object->date => $object->category);
     }
}
```

Which almost works, the problem is that the key gets overridden, so I end up with only one date.

Comment: What attempts have you made?

Comment: You should learn about arrays : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$output = array();
foreach ($array as $object) {
    $output[$object->category][$object->date] = $object->value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop this:

```
$array[$obj->category][$obj->date] = $obj->value;
```

FYI you've spent more time formatting your question than it would take you to google it yourself.